# How to get unique pairs of numbers in matlab where both numbers have not repeated in the matrix before

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have an input matrix as below

```
all = [12 16;12 13;8 14;14 19;3 6;8 6;13 25;25 14;7 2];
```

I need the following output

```
output = [12 16;8 14;3 6;13 25;7 2];
```

The explanation for the output is as follows.

First row of input i.e. `12 16` is the first row in output as both the numbers have never been repeated before in the output matrix (obviously).

Second row of input i.e `12 13` is not needed as the number `12` is present in first row of output i.e repeated

Third row of input i.e `8 14` is second row of output as both the numbers have never been repeated before in the output matrix.

Fourth row of input i.e `14 19` is not needed as the  number `14` is present in output i.e repeated

On similar lines 
`3 6` needed as both are not repeated,

`8 6` not needed as both `8` and `6` are repeated,

`13 25`  needed as both are not repeated

`25 14` not needed as both are repeated

`7 2` needed as both are not repeated

I am not able to get any ideas to start. Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: notice that 13,25 shouldnt be in the output, since 13 is a repeated value

Comment: What if a row has two equal values? Does the second-column value count as a repetition of the first-column value?

Comment: @Ibezito sorry I made some changes to the output itself as my requirement changed , but your solution works for me and I thank you for it!

Comment: @LuisMendo I have made sure that the input does not contain equal values

Comment: happy to help, good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**One Liner Solution**

```
res = all(arrayfun(@(ii) isempty(intersect(all(1:ii-1,:),all(ii,:))),1:size(all,1)),:);
```

**Result**

```
res =

12    16
 8    14
 3     6
 7     2
```

**Explanation**

let's divide the one-liner into a more detailed and documented chunk of code:

```
%defines a function which validates for each index wheter the row is
%completely unique are not.
uniqueRowIndicator = @(ii) isempty(intersect(all(1:ii-1,:),all(ii,:)));

%finds all the unique row in the matrix
inds = arrayfun(uniqueRowIndicator,1:size(all,1));

%extracts the result from the returned indices
res = all(inds,:);
```

Answer (score 1):

This assumes that if a row contains two equal values they count as repeated and thus the row should be removed.

Don't use `all` as a variable name, because that shadows a function:

```
A = [12 16;12 13;8 14;14 19;3 6;8 6;13 25;25 14;7 2]; % input matrix
[~, u] = unique(A.', 'first'); % unique values of linearized transposed A.
    % In recent Matlab versions you an remove 'first '
M = false(flip(size(A))); % initiallize mask of values to be kept
M(u) = true; % fill values
output = A(all(M,1),:); % keep rows that only have non-repeated values
```

This gives

```
output =
    12    16
     8    14
     3     6
     7     2
```

Comment: Thank you for the different approach compared to the first answer. But i had to give it to that user!